# Replace char if not between "\'" char

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that represent an action,
each arg in the action is seporated by the char ';',
for each arg I want to replace the char ',' with the char '.' but only if the ',' is not between ' char using Regex replace

For example:

```
1- "ActionName('1,b';1,2)"
2- "ActionName('a,b';1,2;1.2;'1,3')"
```

Desire result:

```
1- "ActionName('1,b';1.2)"
2- "ActionName('a,b';1.2;1.2;'1,3')
```

Conditions:

The ',' can appear multiple times inside a string.

Currntly I split the string for ';' loop over all the parts and each part I split for '\''.

Example Code:

```
public string Transform(string expression)
{
    string newExpression = string.Empty;
    string[] expParts = expression.Split(';');
    for (int i = 0; i < expParts.Length; i++)
    {
        string newSubExpression = string.Empty;
        string[] subExpParts = expParts[i].Split(new char[] { '\'' });
        for (int subIndex = 0; subIndex < subExpParts.Length; subIndex += 2)
        {
            newSubExpression += subExpParts[subIndex].Replace(',', ".");
            if (subIndex < subExpParts.Length - 1)
                newSubExpression += "\'" + subExpParts[subIndex + 1] + "\'";
        }
        newExpression += newSubExpression;

        if (i < expParts.Length - 1)
            newExpression = newExpression + ",";
    }
    return newExpression;
 }
```

Comment: Why are the middle `,`-s replaced in example 2 as they are also surrounded by `'`-characters. Please revise your rules and examples.

Comment: I've updated the question to be clearer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(?<=^([^']|'[^']*')*),`

```
var myPattern= "(?<=^([^']|'[^']*')*),";
var regex = new Regex(myPattern);
var result = regex.Replace("ActionName('a,b';1,2;1.2;'1,3')", ".");
```

**Output**

```
ActionName('a,b';1.2;1.2;'1,3')
```

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/unA6C6)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged the question a regex, I post a regex that works for your input (at least what you posted):

```
(,(?![\w\d]*'))
```

Just an example, I think that it can be useful for you as a starting point...

You need to replace the matching regex with a ., in C# you can do like this:

```
result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(,(?![\w\d]*'))", @".");
```

Take a look at [regex lookaround](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

A simple **FSM** (*Finite State Machine*) will do. Please, notice that we have just *two* states (encoded with `inQuotation`): are we within quotated chunk or not.

```
   public static string Transform(string expression) {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(expression))
       return expression; // Or throw ArgumentNullException

     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(expression.Length);

     bool inQuotation = false;

     foreach (char c in expression) 
       if (c == ',' && !inQuotation)
         sb.Append('.');
       else {
         if (c == '\'')
           inQuotation = !inQuotation; 

         sb.Append(c);
       }  

     return sb.ToString(); 
   }
```

Tests:

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "ActionName('1,b';1,2)",
    "ActionName('a,b';1,2;1.2;'1,3')",
  };

  var result = tests
    .Select((line, index) => $"{index + 1}- {Transform(line)}");

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
  1- ActionName('1,b';1.2)
  2- ActionName('a,b';1.2;1.2;'1,3')
```